# How to create service bus trigger webjob?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-webjobs

I check the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#service-bus-trigger-configuration-version-3x) use the below code to configure the webjob to create service bus trigger function.

```
    static void Main()
{
    var builder = new HostBuilder();
    builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
    {
        b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
        b.AddServiceBus(sbOptions =>
        {
            sbOptions.MessageHandlerOptions.AutoComplete = true;
            sbOptions.MessageHandlerOptions.MaxConcurrentCalls = 16;
        });
    });
    var host = builder.Build();
    using (host)
    {

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

However when I try to implement it, the `AddServiceBus` method is not available, even add the service bus trigger function it always reports **No job functions found** error.

So where is the configuration error, thanks for any help.

Comment: A WebJob is not the same as Function. Webjob is continuously polling for your messages and running 24/7. A WebJob can _also_ host functions, that are invoked. Can you elaborate what are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to deploy a Function or want to deploy a WebJob that would contain Function(s)?

Comment: I just want to create service bus trigger webjob.

Comment: Have you seen this document: [Get started with the Azure WebJobs SDK for event-driven background processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started)? It's a good start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per my experience when you create the webjob you are not using the correct package. If you check the [service bus binding doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#packages---functions-2x), you will find it need `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus` to provide Service Bus bindings.

And under my test, the follow packages are what you need:

1. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs(>= 3.0.10)
2. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions
3. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus
4. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus

With `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus`, you will be able to use `b.AddServiceBus()` method and with `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus` to create `ServiceBusTrigger` function.

The below is my test code, have a try.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new HostBuilder();
        builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
        {
            b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
            b.AddServiceBus();
        });
        builder.ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
        {
            b.AddConsole();
        });
        var host = builder.Build();
        using (host)
        {
            host.Run();
        }
    }
```

Function.cs

```
public static void processservicebus(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("test", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]string myQueueItem,
    ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation(myQueueItem);
    }
```

[image]

Hope this could help you, if you still have other problem please feel free to let me know.

Comment: where is ServiceBusConnection defined?