# How to implement a triggerless .NET Core Console App as a continuous Azure WebJob?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

All the code samples I've seen so far for Azure WebJobs rely on some kind of trigger (e.g. `TimerTrigger` or `QueueTrigger`).
I am looking specifically at `WebJobs SDK 3.x`, by the way.

So. For a triggerless WebJob (Windows Service-alike one), am I expected to use `NoAutomaticTrigger` and find a way to kickoff my "main" code manually?

Or should I resort to implementing and registering a class that implements the `IHostedService` interface?
So far that's the approach I'm taking but it feels more of a hack than a recommended way.
I have not even tried to deploy this code and only ran it on my local machine, so I am afraid that the publishing process will confirm my code is not suitable for Azure WebJobs in its current form.

---

**EntryPoint.cs**

This is how the application is being bootstrap when the process is starting.

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace AbcCorp.Jobs
{
    public static class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", false)
                .Build();

            var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureWebJobs(builder => { builder.AddAzureStorageCoreServices(); })
                .ConfigureServices(serviceCollection =>
                {
                    ConfigureServices(serviceCollection, config);
                    serviceCollection.AddHostedService<ConsoleApplication>();
                });

            using (var host = hostBuilder.Build())
                await host.RunAsync();
        }

        private static IServiceCollection ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationRoot configuration)
        {
            services.AddTransient<ConsoleApplication>();
            // ... more DI registrations
            return services;
        }
    }
}
```

**ConsoleApplication.cs**

This would normally be implemented as a function with a trigger.
The thing is, I want this code to only run once on the process startup.
It will start listening on the service bus events using the regular `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` SDK package.

```cs
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using AbcCorp.Internal.Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;
using AbcCorp.Api.Messaging;

namespace AbcCorp.Jobs
{
    public sealed class ConsoleApplication: IHostedService
    {
        private readonly IReceiver<SubmissionNotification> _messageReceiver;
        private readonly MessageHandler _messageHandler;

        public ConsoleApplication(IReceiver<SubmissionNotification> messageReceiver, MessageHandler messageHandler)
        {
            _messageReceiver = messageReceiver;
            _messageHandler = messageHandler;
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _messageReceiver.StartListening(_messageHandler.HandleMessage, _messageHandler.HandleException);
            return Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite);
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _messageReceiver.Dispose();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not try the service bus trigger webjob?

Comment: @george Because that wasn't the intended design of the system I'm working on. Is there a way to achieve what I'm asking or usage of some kind of a trigger is mandated?

Comment: Firstly the service bus trigger webjob actually is a continuous webjob. Then if your console function is ok, suppose you could deploy it as continuous webjob directly just like a simple hello world console app. If you don't use webjob sdk, then no much form to meet.

Comment: @GeorgeChen I re-read your comment three times and still don't get it. If you have an idea of how to get a self-sufficient console app working in Azure WebJobs environment without using triggers — please write an answer and I'll sure upvote it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

So you want a console application to run in a WebJob and listen to messages. You don't really care about WebJob magic like triggers, it's just a place to run your console app. I've done the exact same thing before.

I found the `IHostedService` abstraction to be very helpful, but I didn't like their SDK. I found it bloated and hard to use. I didn't want to take a large dependency in order use a large array of special magic Azure stuff, when all I wanted to do was run a console application in a WebJob for now, and maybe move it elsewhere later.

So I ended just deleting that dependency, stealing the Shutdown code from the SDK and writing my own Service Host. The result is on my Github Repo [azure-webjob-host](https://github.com/NathanLBCooper/azure-webjob-host). Feel free to use it or raid it for ideas. I don't know, maybe if I did it again I'd have another attempt at getting the SDK to work, but I present this is a bit of an alternative to the SDK.

Basically I wrote an IServiceHost not too different from yours (except that `StartAsync` exited when stuff started instead of just hanging). Then I wrote my own service host, which is basically just a loop:

```
await _service.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
while (!token.IsCancellationRequested){await Task.Delay(1000);}
await _service.StopAsync(default);
```

Then I stole the `WebJobsShutdownWatcher` code [from their repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/WebjobsShutdownWatcher.cs).

Then I created an `IServiceHost` that started my message handler. (I was using Rabbit, which has nothing to do with triggers or azure stuff)

```
public class MessagingService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    public MessagingService(ConnectionSettings connectionSettings,
        AppSubscriberSettings subscriberSettings,
        MessageHandlerTypeMapping[] messageHandlerTypeMappings,
        ILogger<MessagingService> logger)
    {
        ....
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        await Task.WhenAll(subscribers.Value.Select(s => s.StartSubscriptionAsync()));
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ...
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then I put that all together into something like this:

```
IHostedService myService = new MyService();

using (var host = new ServiceHostBuilder().HostService(myService))
{
    await host.RunAsync(default);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have some workers attached to service bus topics and what we do is the following (ServiceBusClient is a custom Class that contains our Subscription Client):

```
public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _serviceBusClient.RegisterOnMessageHandlerAndReceiveMessages(MessageReceivedAsync);

        _logger.LogDebug($"Started successfully the Import Client. Listening for messages...");
        return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
    }


        public void RegisterOnMessageHandlerAndReceiveMessages(Func<Message, CancellationToken, Task> ProcessMessagesAsync)
    {
        // Configure the message handler options in terms of exception handling, number of concurrent messages to deliver, etc.
        var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
        {
            // Maximum number of concurrent calls to the callback ProcessMessagesAsync(), set to 1 for simplicity.
            // Set it according to how many messages the application wants to process in parallel.
            MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,

            // Indicates whether MessagePump should automatically complete the messages after returning from User Callback.
            // False below indicates the Complete will be handled by the User Callback as in `ProcessMessagesAsync` below.
            AutoComplete = false
        };

        // Register the function that processes messages.
        SubscriptionClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ProcessMessagesAsync, messageHandlerOptions);
    }
```

And then you can use DI to instantiate your service bus client and inject on the constructor of your Worker class.

Here i have the initialization of the singleton instance of my custom class Service Bus Client

```
services.AddSingleton<IServiceBusClient, ServiceBusClient>((p) =>
                {

                    var diagnostics = p.GetService<EventHandling>();
                    var sbc = new ServiceBusClient(
                        programOptions.Endpoint,
                        programOptions.TopicName,
                        programOptions.Subscriber,
                        programOptions.SubscriberKey);

                    sbc.Exception += exception => diagnostics.HandleException(exception);

                    return sbc;
                });
```

Then on this custom class, i initialize my subscription client

```
public ServiceBusClient(
        string endpoint,
        string topicName,
        string subscriberName,
        string subscriberKey, ReceiveMode mode = ReceiveMode.PeekLock)
    {
        var connBuilder = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(endpoint, topicName, subscriberName, subscriberKey);
        var connectionString = connBuilder.GetNamespaceConnectionString();

        ConnectionString = connectionString;
        TopicName = topicName;
        SubscriptionName = topicName;

        SubscriptionClient = new SubscriptionClient(connectionString, topicName, subscriberName, mode);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! Could you please show the gist of your Program.cs or whatever the entry point class is? I'm interested to see how different my setup is from yours with regards to DI configuration, service instantiation, and launch. This should be sufficient for me to proceed as well as accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Upvoted. This seems to be not a .NET Core solution but .NET Framework if I am not mistaken.

Comment: No Igor. This is using .NET Core 3.0

Answer (score 0):

You can check @george chen's answer from this post [How to create service bus trigger webjob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58647763/how-to-create-service-bus-trigger-webjob)

where instead of creating a receiver and registering a message handler, you can use the in built queue trigger and and write your message handler logic inside it.

Comment: Two reasons. 1. I have a working code, I am constraint in time, and I'm trying to avoid adding more actors to my design. 2. I don't WANT to have a trigger in the first place. But rather have my own listener code deployed in a Windows service alike manner.